# Finding unknowns in basic vectors for which it is parallel to another vector

Tags: vectors

Struggling with the question

A and B are the points (2, 4) and (0, 7). P is a point on the line AB:

(b) Find the value of  for which  is parallel to 2**i** − 2**j**

I have written the point OP as the vector $(2-2\lambda)\textbf{i} + (4+3\lambda)\textbf{j}$ but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Have you tried using the cross product?

Comment: @URL I've read about that but that's not something that we've covered in class a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make $\color{blue}{(2-2\lambda)}\textbf{i} + \color{blue}{(4+3\lambda)}\textbf{j}$ parallel to $\color{green}2\mathbf i-\color{green}2\mathbf j$,

set $\color{blue}{2-2\lambda}=\color{green}2\kappa$ and $\color{blue}{4+3\lambda}=\color{green}{-2}\kappa$.

Add both equations and solve for $\lambda.$